# Preferred way of breaking up AJAX updates to multiple database tables in NodeJS

Tags: mysql, node.js, postgresql

This should be a pretty common issue: let's say I'm updating a `users` table as well as a `users_organizations` table.  From the UI perspective, there is only one button "Save".

I can either:

1) Create a single API route
2) Create one API route for each resource (one for `users`, one for `users_organizations`)

And then, suppose I choose 1).  Should I update both tables in a single database call or should I split it up into 2 database calls?

In general I'm never sure how to approach these problems.  Sometimes there's an action that affects more than 2 database tables at once.  How do I ensure robustness, proper error handling, and keep my code sane all at once?

Comment: You should read about databases, and specifically about transactions. You should do a single API call and update the two tables inside a transaction.

Comment: thank you @vitaly-t! btw big fan of pg-promise here :)

Comment: Well, in that case you're in for a treat, because `pg-promise` handles transactions automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely a problem I struggle with as well.

From what I've seen in the past, most operations that go along with a UI action are related, and can be given a common action name like  `update-user` when clicking "Save". I'd have a single API endpoint to update the user, such as `PUT /api/users/123` in a REST API. The body of that request would contain updated fields and new organizations the user belongs to.

Then on the server side I would make 2 database calls, one to update the `user` table and one to update the `user_organization` table.

If you feel 2 operations are so different that it's difficult to come up with a common API endpoint name, or if they need to be called independently in other parts of the app, I would argue that they should be 2 different API endpoints.

At the end of the day I try to ask, if a new developer were to try to understand this code, what would be the simplest approach?